# Install OpenSSL Support for self-compiled Ruby Installation

Tags: ruby, openssl

I unpacked and compiled Ruby 2.1 and installed several support tools.

But OpenSSL won't install while I have libssl-dev installed.

I get this error when making the openssl support:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/thread_native.h', needed by `ossl.o'.  Stop.
```

What to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Turns out, the last line of the extconf.rb-generated Makefile reads

```
ossl.o: $(top_srcdir)/thread_native.h $(top_srcdir)/thread_$(THREAD_MODEL).h
```

However, `top_srcdir` isn't defined anywhere in the Makefile.

I figured out where the missing header files were by running

```
sudo find / -name thread_native.h
```

which returned (approximately)

```
~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/thread_native.h
```

There's a line at the top that says something like

```
topdir = ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0
```

so I just added a line below it pointing to the directory from the `find`:

```
top_srcdir = $(topdir)/../..
```

After all that, I did a `make clean` in the `ext/openssl` directory and then `make` ran without the error.

Comment: had to add the ruby directory of the downloaded source as the `top_srcdir` in the Makefile. worked fine then.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use rvm? It compiles, configures, installs and manages the chosen version of the most popular ruby interpreters for you.

Anyway, try using `--with-openssl-dir`.